# HAML tag confusion

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I wish to construct the following in haml:

```
<div class="cell", id="cell11">
  more stuff..
</div>
```

where cell11 above is actually a ruby snippet of the form

```
<%= cell.html_id %>  (as coded in erb)
```

I cannot seem to construct a haml line that works in this case.  The best I can get is a div with a class, followed by a div with an id...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ID is dynamic, just set the the id attribute like this:

```
.cell{:id => cell.html_id}
  more stuff..
```

Otherwise, you can just string the id and class(es) together as in:

```
.#myID.cell.foo.bar.etc
  more stuff...
```

which would yield

```
<div id="myID" class="cell foo bar etc">
more stuff...
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, your first option worked fine.  I am new to haml and just getting the hang of it.

Comment: I would be happy to upvote and 'accept', if I knew what those were... I find this site very helpful to me.

Comment: An upvote means you click the up arrow next to my answer to mark it as a good answer.  Clicking the check mark allows you, the asker to mark my answer as the one that best answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why there is a comma in your div tag.  I don't think that's valid HTML.

You can make

```
<div class="cell" id="cell11">
  more stuff.. 
</div>
```

like this:

```
%div.cell#cell11
  more stuff..
```

or more tersely,

```
.cell#cell11
  more stuff..
```

The HAML tag format is similar to CSS selectors.